# Laravel JsonResource (resource collection) add extra data to response

Tags: php, laravel, resources

I'm working with laravel (v7) resources and I have a resource that extends `JsonResource` and I call this resource from the controller with pagination. I would like to add additional attribute `extra` next to the `data` array as follow:

```
{
    "data": [
    ],
    "links": {
    },
    "meta": {
    },
    "extra": {
        ....
    }
}
```

The problem with JsonResource is that they don't work `with` with method. I tried to add the following to my resource collection but it did not make any difference.

```
    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'extra' => [
                'key' => 'value',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The only way so far I found that works is when additional() method is called from within the controller chained to the resource itself like:

```
return (new UserCollection(User::all()->load('roles')))
                ->additional(['extra' => [
                    'key' => 'value',
                ]]);
```

But I want to add some data from the resource itself and this extra data is not available in the controller. Is there anyway to do this?

Edit:
Here is my Resource collection

```
class UserCollection extends JsonResource
{

    protected $result = [];


    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $this->result = [
            
            "attributes" =>[
                 "id"                   => $this->id,
                'name'                  => $this->name,
                'position'              => $this->position,
            ],
        ] ;

        return $this->result;
    }


    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'extra' => [
                'key' => 'value',
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

And this is how it is called from the controller

```
$users = User::where('is_available', 1)->get();

$users = $users->paginate();    

return UserCollection::collection($users);
```

Comment: Hi, it should work if you added with function inside resource collection, and its hard to tell by looking only few part of file. Can you past complete file of your resource and resource collection and the Laravel version which you are using.

Comment: @Deepak please see my edit. Unfortunately, `with()` had no effect.

Comment: class `UserCollection` extends `JsonResource ` it should extends `ResourceCollection`

Comment: If I extend it from ResourceCollection I won't be able to customize the returned attributes.

Comment: okay for that make two files by running `php artisan make:resource user` and `php artisan make:resource userCollection` . this will generate two separate files in same folder, use `user.php` which is JsonResource to customize your attributes and use `userCollection.php`  file to customize/adding meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `JsonResource` and `ResourceCollection` in two files by running `php artisan make:resource user` and `php artisan make:resource userCollection`.

You will have two separate files in same folder, `user.php` and `userCollection.php`.

use user.php which is JsonResource to customize your attributes and use userCollection.php

for reference  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections